# VBA COUNTA Userform

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, countif

I have a Userform with several textboxes and a command button. When the  information is entered and submitted the information is transfered to the first empty row.

I need a code that would `counta()` text within 4 columns within that row. So translate `=IF(IsBlank($A2),"",COUNTA(E2:H2)` to VBA code to calculate after the user submitted the information.

Comment: It would help to post the actual code you have been piecing together. Cause after you have transfered over your value, you wouldn't need any formula at all to get what you are after.

Comment: xCtr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:H2"))   might be part of what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Debug.Print "Var 1 : "; CountRangeIf("not(A3="""")", Range("E3:H3"))

    Dim testCriteria As Boolean
    testCriteria = Not (Range("A3").Value = "")
    Debug.Print "Var 2 : "; CountRangeIf_Var2(testCriteria, Range("E3:H3"))
End Sub

Public Function CountRangeIf(IfCriteriaString As String, CountRange As Range) As Variant
    Dim resultCriteria As Boolean
    CountRangeIf = ""           ' Result = "" if Criteria is false
    resultCriteria = Evaluate(IfCriteriaString)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If resultCriteria Then
            CountRangeIf = .CountA(CountRange)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function CountRangeIf_Var2(IfCriteria As Boolean, CountRange As Range) As Variant
    CountRangeIf_Var2 = ""           ' Result = "" if Criteria is false
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If IfCriteria Then
            CountRangeIf_Var2 = .CountA(CountRange)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This works thanks, the only thing is i need this code to run on each row after I click  the commandbutton, as im using a userform that when filled out populates the cells from A to N and giving me a count on cells E to H before moving to the next row.

Comment: Call the function `CountRangeIf()`when you need it as part of your `commandbutton_click()` function!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming we're using Sheet1 
and presuming your Row # is already stored in 
ThisRowNum variable

Following should be close to what you asked for

```
    If Trim(CStr(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & ThisRowNum).Value)) = "" then
       xCtr = 0  ' Your formula used a null string - you can fix this
    else
       xCtr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & ThisRowNum &":H" & ThisRowNum))
    endif
```

The xCtr variable is the result